# python's logging module is not logging to a log file

Tags: python

I am trying out python's logger module to log info both in console and in a log and it works fine.I wanted that script to get invoked during machine star-tup and hence invoked my script from rc.local.

And my script gets invoked during boot-up, but the problem is, only console logging is working at that time. Logging to a file is not happening. Any clue on what could be the issue.

Is it anything related to syslog daemon?

```
import time
import logging
import datetime

global logger
global LOG_FILE

def initialize():
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    time = datetime.datetime.now()
    LOG_FILE = "sample.log." + time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    log_file_handler = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILE)
    log_file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    log_file_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
    log_file_handler.setFormatter(log_file_formatter)
    logger.addHandler(log_file_handler)

    log_file_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    log_file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    log_file_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
    log_file_handler.setFormatter(log_file_formatter)    
    logger.addHandler(log_file_handler)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    initialize()
    logger.info("This should go both in console and log")
    logger.debug("This should go only to Log")
```

Comment: Without seeing any of the code in question, no. No idea.

Comment: Have pasted the code. Like i said earlier, when i invoke this script from rc.local, only console logging works. Log file is never getting generated.

Comment: thats not how globals work. `global` is to be used inside of functions to reference that a variables being used is global. `logger` and `LOG_FILE` should just be set where you have `global logger`, then in the initialize function put `global logger, LOG_FILE` as the first line.   Also I would suggest putting a full path to the log file, such as `/var/log/sample.log`, that way it doesn't matter where the script is executed from.

Answer (score 1):

```
import time
import logging
import datetime

def initialize():
    # because logging is global module, so you can 
    # always get logger by logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    time = datetime.datetime.now()
    # if you only use LOG_FILE in function, you don't
    # have to declare it outside.
    LOG_FILE = "sample.log." + time.strftime("%Y%m%d")
    log_file_handler = logging.FileHandler(LOG_FILE)
    log_file_handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    log_file_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
    log_file_handler.setFormatter(log_file_formatter)
    logger.addHandler(log_file_handler)

    log_file_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
    log_file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
    log_file_formatter = logging.Formatter('%(message)s')
    log_file_handler.setFormatter(log_file_formatter)
    logger.addHandler(log_file_handler)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    initialize()
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.info("This should go both in console and log")
    logger.debug("This should go only to Log")
```